# Como codificar um número com a notação '\x' e não '0x'

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### Problema

Estou realizando uma comunicação serial em que o *checksum* da mensagem precisa ser enviado ou verificado ao receber. Este deve ser verificado com uma lógica XOR, que retorna um número int, dada pela seguinte função:

```
def XOR(hex):
    b = 0
    for a in hex:
        b = a ^ b
    return b
```

Com o seguinte dado de exemplo, em que `x` é a resposta do dispositivo, conforme imagem a seguir:

[image: Pacote de dados]

E `y` são os dados sem o STX (\x02), ETX (\x03) e o checksum.

```
x = b'\x02\x02\x40\x0b\x00\x77\xc0\x00\x03\xfe'
y = x[1:-2]
```

O `XOR()` de `y` é `254` em decimal ou `FE` em hexadecimal, que mostra que a função `XOR()` está correta.

#### Teste

Ao realizar o mesmo procedimento ao enviar uma mensagem, está gerando erro, pois a codificação retorna `0xfe` com `i = hex(254).encode()` ou `i = hex(XOR(y)).encode()`.

Porém, ao inserir o checksum manualmente com `+b'\xfe'` a mensagem é enviada corretamente.

Com o seguinte programa de teste:

```
a=b'0xfe'
b=b'\xfe'
print(int.from_bytes(a, byteorder='big'),int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big'))
```

A seguinte string `813196901 254` é impressa, ou seja, com `b'0xfe'` um erro ocorre também ao converter no Python.

#### Pergunta

Como eu codifico um número com a notação '\x' e não '0x'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `hex` te dá uma representação de string dos bytes passados a ela, e essa representação começa com `0x` pra indicar que é um número hexadecimal. Quando você cria uma variável com `b''`, está criando um objeto `bytes`. São coisas diferentes.

Dentro de uma declaração de `bytes` nesse formato, o `\x` é uma sequência de escape que indica que o que vem a seguir não são os bytes equivalentes aos caracteres "f" e "e", por exemplo, mas sim ao número que corresponde em hexadecimal a "FE" (254). Então os seguintes são realmente coisas diferentes:

```
a=b'0xfe'  # Declara os bytes \x30 \x78 \x66 \x65 (os quatro bytes que em ACII são 0 x f e)
b=b'\xfe'  # Declara um único byte \xFE (254)

>>> b'0xfe' == b'\x30\x78\x66\x65'
True
```

O que você quer fazer com seu número é convertê-lo diretamente pra um objeto `bytes`, sem passar por uma string:

```
i = 254
i_bytes = i.to_bytes(1, 'big')
```

Resultado:

```
b = b'\xfe'

i = 254
i_bytes = i.to_bytes(1, 'big')
print(i_bytes)  # b'\xfe'

print(int.from_bytes(i_bytes, byteorder='big'), int.from_bytes(b, byteorder='big'))  # 254 254
print(type(b))        # <class 'bytes'>
print(type(i_bytes))  # <class 'bytes'>
```